# Should resistor R1 be in the gate of the CMOS transistor of the following schematic? (CMOS Transistor)

Tags: cmos, gate-driving

I'm analyzing the following circuit that is used to activate and deactivate a CMOS transistor which is used as a switch:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzvHPK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I think that R1 should not be and the M3 gate should be connected directly to the driver's output.

Am I right?

Any comment or suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Where did you get this circuit? Didn't it come with any explanation?

Comment: It is a Chinese product. The PCB was analyzed and the schematic was obtained. Not much information readable for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the gate driver is there to drive enough current to quickly turn the FET on or off, the R1 of 1kohm seems a bit too large and defeats the purpose of a fast FET control with a gate driver. It might not matter a lot with slow signals if a load is turned on and off at slow rate, but if the load is driven with fast PWM signal it will matter. It can be easily reduced to 100 or 10 ohms, and it will usually cause no adverse effects.

Omitting it completely can cause too large currents, and too fast rise/fall times, and any stray inductances of too long wiring and FET capacitances can cause ringing, which is something you might want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the IXDI602 is a 40V ~2 ohm switch and the FET must be a lower resistance switch, it’s gate resistance will be relatively on the same order of magnitude as the ‘602 . Depending on the path length and parasitic ESL and rise time, you must consider matching the resistance of driver and gate with a small R when fall/rise-times and slew rates are critical. otherwise it doesn’t matter.